# windows shortcut icon showing as two different icons

Tags: windows, icons, desktop-icons

What would cause a desktop shortcut to have two different icons depending on what size the desktop icons are set to?

I had one icon, and then later changed the icon file, replacing it with a new icon. When I assign the icon to the shortcut, it works fine if I have the icon size set to small. However, if I change to using medium or large icons, the old version of the icon still appears.

Edit: One detail is that the shortcut was to a `.accde` file.

Comment: That depends on how the resources (e.g. images, etc.) are added to that executable. You can configure/change those resources with [Resource Hacker](http://angusj.com/resourcehacker/).

Comment: @Biswa  I'll have to keep that program in mind. I found a different solution though.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So apparently windows doesn't let go of the past very well. The old icons were cached in memory and wouldn't change back even after a restart. The fix was to run:

```
ie4uinit -show
```

which according to [winaero's website](http://winaero.com/blog/fix-broken-icons-reset-icon-cache-in-windows-10-without-reboot/), forces windows to refresh the cache.

Comment: Your answer does not match with your question. I have more to say. May I post that in a new answer?

Comment: @Biswa  Sure. I don't know how they don't match though...

Answer (score 0):

Let's take an example of empty Recycle Bin shortcut. The default icon of empty bin is **%SystemRoot%\System32\imageres.dll,-55**. These icons can be find in imageres.dll file in System32 folder. Open imageres.dll (Windows Image Resource) in [Resource Hacker](http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/). Go to icon group folder and open #55 group (as shown).

[image: imageres.dll_icons]

Here you see the icons from #500 to #507 are the empty recycle bin icons depending on their icon dimensions. Open icon folder in resource hacker, you can see the icons from #500 to #507 (image below).

[image: icon_thumbnails]

Hence when you change the icon size, it changes according to the dimensions of that icons (see the animation). Icon sizes can be changed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>+</kbd> keys.

[image: Recycle Bin animation]

Comment: Yes, I see how resource hacker works, and I tested it on a few shortcuts to .exe files. The problem is that this shortcut is for an access .accde and for some reason resource hacker will not open those. I will change my question to include that.

Comment: That depends on which application is associated with that .accde file type.

Comment: It opens in access runtime.  The target path has the path of the file with ` /runtime` at the end.

Comment: The answer I put down worked for me. Thanks for the answer, but it seems I was working with a special case somehow.